# .change() hide <select> .click() .show() <select>

Tags: jquery, select, hide, show

I want to hide a select box after choosing an option and put in place the value as text. That is what's working. The next thing I need is, to be able to click on the text and show the select box again. That's NOT working right now.

Does anyone knows what to do??? Please? :-D

```
<a>
  <select class="trigger">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</a> 
<a>
  <select class="trigger">
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
        <option value="d">d</option>
  </select>
</a>

<script>
$('.trigger').change( function() {
    var $tt = $(this).val();
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent("a").text($tt);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `text()` or `html()` will replace the contents of the parent anchor, removing the select dropdown completely, when all you really want to do is just to hide it :

```
$('.trigger').on('change', function() {
    var elem = $(this),
        txt  = $('<span />', {text: this.value});

    elem.hide().before(txt);
    txt.on('click', function() {
        elem.show();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Yve/2/)

Comment: This is probably the best one: simple and elegant solution. Rgds,

Comment: Only thing now is, that when you click, you cannot immediately use the same value. You need to first choose another before selecting that one again. Can you help?

Comment: @user2375199 - that is how the change event works, it's only triggered if there is a change. If you select the same option twice, the change event is not fired the second time. You can try using click instead, and that will probably solve the issue, but then using the keyboard to change the select no longer works, only mouse clicks.

Comment: Worked it out by adding an extra <option>...</option> and changed elem.show(); to elem.show().val("1"); So now it's going back to option 1. Not really what I wanted but it's okay

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    self.addClass('edited').next('span').text(self.val());
});

$('#optionList span').click(function () {
    $(this).prev('select').removeClass('edited').focus();
});
```

With the following CSS:

```
select.edited,
select + span {
    display: none;
}

#optionList select.edited + span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And HTML (change as required):

```
<ul id="optionList">
    <li>
        <select name="one">
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
            <option>Three</option>
            <option>Four</option>
        </select> <span></span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ADWBK/).

You could, though, use CSS for most of this functionality:

```
<ul id="optionList">
    <li>
        <select name="one">
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
            <option>Three</option>
            <option>Four</option>
        </select><span></span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

With the CSS:

```
select {
    border: 0 none transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

select:focus + span::after {
    color: #000;
}

span::after {
    color: #999;
    content:'\25bc'; /* unicode down-pointing arrow: '▼' */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ADWBK/2/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Thx for your answer. I tried the first one, but that somehow didn't work. Gonna use the one of adeneo.

Comment: Well, it works in the linked demo; did you remember to change the selectors in the CSS and the jQuery?

Comment: Hahaha that's a good one! I just copy pasted your example to see if it worked. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('option').click(function(){
      var value = $(this).attr('value');
      $(this).parents('a').html(value);
    });
  });
```

EDIT: I think your issue may have actually been that you didn't wrap your jQuery in doc ready? I've added that in, but I think your original method may work with the doc ready.

Comment: please do not use `.attr('value');`. Either do `.prop('value')` or `.val()`

Comment: Thx for the advice Ilia G! Will do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('.trigger').change(function () {
        var $tt = $(this).val();
        $(this).hide();
        // Don't use .text(), that will replace the <select> with the text
        $(this).parent("a").append($("<span/>", {
            text: $tt
        }));
    });
    $("a").click(function () {
        // If the select is hidden ...
        var $select = $(".trigger:hidden", $(this));
        if ($select.length) {
            // Remove the text field ...
            $("span", $(this)).remove();
            // and show the select
            $select.show();
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/zScGJ/1/)

Comment: Sorry man, but that's not working over here. It adds the text (value) in front of the select box. So I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: It's not hiding the select box? I'm not sure why.

Comment: Fixed. I had `"div"` where it should be `"span"`.

Comment: It works in the fiddle, you must be doing something different. In a real page it would probably be best to give the `a` tags a class so you can bind the click handler to that class rather than all anchors.

Comment: I've copied my code from the fiddle just in case there was an editing mistake.

Comment: Guess I'm doing something wrong then. But the one of adeneo is working good for me. Thx anyways :-)

Answer (score 0):

Following is a simple solution (http://jsfiddle.net/h7ynd/):

**HTML**

```
<a>
  <select id="trigger1">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>

</a>
 <span id="label1"></span>

<a>
  <select id="trigger2">
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
        <option value="d">d</option>
  </select>
   <span id="label2"></span>
</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#trigger1').change(function () {
    var $tt = $(this).val();
    $('#label1').text($tt )
    $(this).hide();
});
$('#label1').click(function () {
    $("#trigger1").show();
    $(this).text("");
});

$('#trigger2').change(function () {
    var $tt = $(this).val();
    $('#label2').text($tt )
    $(this).hide();
});
$('#label2').click(function () {
    $("#trigger2").show();
    $(this).text("");
});
```

Selectors can be modified to use classes instead of id.

Comment: Thx for your asnswer, but I'm using the one of adeneo

Comment: I would say, it's a right choice. Good luck with your project! Rgds,